# A complexity-class of problems that cannot be solved in finite time

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, computing-over-reals

Is there a complexity class for problems such as the following?

**Problem FindSum(s)**, where $s\in[0,1]$ is a real parameter:

**Input**: $g: [0,1]\to [0,1]$, a continuous monotone-increasing bijective function, specified by oracles that can answer queries of two kinds:

- Given $x\in[0,1]$, what is $g(x)$?
- Given $\alpha\in[0,1]$, what is $g^{-1}(\alpha)$?

**Output**: A point $x_0\in[0,1-s]$ for which $g(x_0) +g(x_0+s)=1$.

The problem definition is somewhat similar to definition of PPAD problems: in PPAD problems, too, the input is given by two complementary oracles ("previous node" and "next node"), and a solution is guaranteed to exist.
However, the problem above considers arbitrary real numbers, as in the [Real RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_RAM) model. Moreover, it can be proved that the problem cannot be solved by finitely many queries.

One can think of many similar problems. Is there a complexity class for them?

Comment: Maybe some languages defined by [Büchi automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Büchi_automaton), depending on what you mean by "query".